# Handle config files in Python

Tags: python, configuration-files

I'm playing with Python to develop a simple app focused on text processing. For this to work, I need the user to add some info and configure a buch of variables (if needed). So I was thinking in having a config file. I've been reading a lot about it (ini files and configparser mostly) but I have some questions:

- Where is the best location to place config files? Is it right to use [appdirs](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/appdirs/1.4.0) for this?
- As I need default values, how should I handle this? Should I generate it on the first launch? Is there any project doing this? I would like to take a look, but I don't find any.

Comment: I personnaly prefer when the config file is in the same directory as the program (or in subfolders).
I find it annoying to have to go to a deep place to find them.

Comment: @Morb maybe I'm saying something stupid but, what happens when I install the app using pip? I'll have an script to launch it, but where will be the config file?

Comment: Sorry, I can't tell, I've never used pip

Comment: It will be wherever you put it. On linux the home folder is where a lot of applications keep their config files. I presume the config is updated when the user makes a change in the app so looking for the config file is not an issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it right to use appdirs for this?

If you intend to install the app in different platforms, using `appdirs` seems to me like an appropriate choice.

> As I need default values, how should I handle this?

The default configuration, assuming it does not change depending on the installation, the user, the platform, whatever... It makes sense to place it in the app directory.
Otherwise, use `appdirs` as well.

As for the format, if the configuration files are intended to be changed only by the application (and not directly by the user, in a text editor, for example) then just go with the format you feel more comfortable with. There's usually not big difference between them in the eyes of a machine. Although some might be more optimal for some solutions than others, you will find that quite fast by yourself. Anything is good enough, be it `.ini`, `.json`, `.yml`, etc...

Now, if you intend the user to change the configs manually, then you better go with a simple enough format, where the messing-up potential can be reduced. In such cases I usually go with `yaml` with a very simple structure. It gets parsed to a python `dict` and types are usually correctly inferred.

**Example**

```
# user_config.yml
# Some example configuration

paulo:
    age: 25
    city: Berlin

david:
    age: 29
    city: Oviedo
```

---

```
# app.py
# loading the configuration
import yaml

user_config = yaml.load(open('user_config.yml', 'r'))
user_config
{'david': {'age': 29, 'city': 'Oviedo'},
 'paulo': {'age': 25, 'city': 'Berlin'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I place my config files with the application, it is easier to hunt them down.

As for the format, there is [a nice wrietup about the various formats](http://martin-thoma.com/configuration-files-in-python/) which will help you to make up your mind. I have gone to full JSON, with a `_`entry for comments, all loaded via `json.load()`:

```
[
    {
        "_": "the name of the game",
        "name": "Cluedo"
    },
    {
        "_": "number of players",
        "number_of_players": 8
    }
]
```